# Changing ToolBar Activity from Fragment

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the look of the ToolBar, what am I doing wrong ?
[1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2uXP.jpg)
[2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXVlP.jpg)
My code Activity

```
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
             android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical">
                 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                     android:id="@+id/appbar"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
                     <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                         app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
                 <fragment/>
             </LinearLayout>
             <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView />
         </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
   <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainappbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/maincollapsing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mainbackdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder_book"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/maintoolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:title="test"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    />
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Please tell me what do I need to do to fix it ? Perhaps I'll have to change the toolbar ? I tried to hide the toolbar activity but it is a bad solution.
This is what I want to achieve [3 img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plvhx.jpg)

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you want to achieve and what you've tried so far for it?

Comment: @YashKrishan I added a picture of what I want to achieve, I tried a lot, tried to substitute and change the toolbar

Comment: Why are you using two app bar layout?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya I want to change the ToolBar, so I tried to do this

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya So what should I do ?

Comment: you must need to hide app bar layout from activity.